# Bluetooth file transfer failure

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bluetooth

I wanted to send a file with bluetooth from my PC to my smartphone. The smartphone is already paired to the PC.

When I got into the send file wizard, selected the file I wanted to send and clicked on the destination device, it says that it was ***"unable to connect to remote device, please check that the remote device is turned on and properly configured."***

I tried to remove my smartphone from the device manager and re-paired them but to no avail. When the PC wanted to install drivers for the phone's services, only one driver couldn't be installed. The driver was called Bluetooth Peripheral Device.

It worked fine before.

I'm on a 64-bit Windows 7.

Comment: Why don't you start with finding latest driver for the Bluetooth Peripheral Device which didn't install. Start from looking at computer manufacturers website.